# (Google Script) Script check - Send email for new from all new rows in a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

A form feeds into the spreadsheet (Used for raising IT Support Requests) and I would like it to send an email and mark the row as "sent".

The script currently sends an email for every row disregarding the fact that it gets marked as sent.

```
function sendEmail() 
{
   var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
   var StartRow = 2;
   var RowRange = ActiveSheet.getLastRow() - StartRow + 1;
   var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow,1,RowRange,7);
   var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();
   var message = "";
   for (var i=0;i<AllValues.length;i++) 
   {
     var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];
     var EmailSent = CurrentRow[7];
     if (EmailSent != "sent")
     {
        message +=
            "<p><b>Timestamp: </b>" + CurrentRow[0] + "</p>" +
            "<p><b>E-mail: </b>" + CurrentRow[1] + "</p>" +
            "<p><b>Site: </b>" + CurrentRow[2] + "</p>" +  
            "<p><b>Summary: </b>" + CurrentRow[3] + "</p>" +
            "<p><b>Description: </b>" + CurrentRow[4] + "</p>" +
            "<p><b>Attachment: </b>" + CurrentRow[5] + "</p>";
        var setRow = i + StartRow;
        ActiveSheet.getRange(setRow, 7).setValue("sent");
        var SendTo = "itsupport@company.com";
        var Subject = "Support Request - ";
        var replyTo = CurrentRow[1];
       MailApp.sendEmail({to: SendTo,
                          replyTo: replyTo,
                          cc: "",
                          subject: Subject + " [" + CurrentRow[2] + "] " + CurrentRow[3],
                          htmlBody: message,});

    }
  }
}
```

Currently it sends an email for each row marks the row as sent (column 7). Which seems correct  but on the next run it will send an email for the same rows and any new rows that are not marked as sent

Comment: Have you tried using `!==` rather than `!=` in your `if` statement?

Comment: just tested it does the same thing of still re-sending all rows regardless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

Your `if` statement is looking at `CurrentRow[7]`, this is actually column 8 in the sheet, not column 7 like you're expecting.

---

#### Explanation:

Google Apps Script is based on JavaScript. When we do `range.getValues()`, an array of values is returned. Arrays are 0-indexed, meaning to reference the first object of the array, you'd use `array[0]` rather than `array[1]`.

Here's a quick example for you:

```js
var array = ['Item One', 'Item Two', 'Item Three'];
console.log(array[0]);
```

As you can see, when we log `array[0]`, we actually get the first item of the array we're referencing.

---

#### Solution:

All you need to do to fix your code is point your `var EmailSent` to the correct array object like so:

```
var EmailSent = CurrentRow[6];
```

---

#### Reference:

- [JavaScript Arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the initial value from column 8 since the indices are 0 based.

Change

```
var EmailSent = CurrentRow[7];
```

To

```
var EmailSent = CurrentRow[6];
```