# Google App Script - automatically send out email when a new row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to build a script that can automatically send email when a new row is updated. I only want to trigger the new updated rows and mark 'sent' after sending them out.

Here's the script that's currently working well. I can run it with a click:

```
function sendMail() 
{
  var name = 0;
  var request = 1;
  var id = 2;
  var select = 3;
  var time = 4;
  var   email = 5;
  var status = 6;
  var error = 7;

  var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email");
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email list");
  var data = ws.getRange("A2:I" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
  
  data = data.filter(function(r){ return r[8] == true });

  data.forEach(function(row)
  {

    emailTemp.fn = row[name];
    emailTemp.req = row[request];
    emailTemp.id = row[id];
    emailTemp.erm = row[error];
    emailTemp.ta = row[select];
    emailTemp.time = row[time];

    var htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
    GmailApp.sendEmail(row[email], 
    "Failure message", 
    "Please submit again.",
    {name: "My name", htmlBody: htmlMessage}
    );
  });
}
```

I have studied  [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57253995/google-script-script-check-send-email-for-new-from-all-new-rows-in-a-spreads) but I still have no idea how it works.

Please share some relevant source or some solution, thank you!

Comment: Where do you want to reflect `mark 'sent' after sending them out`?

Comment: Hi Tanaike, I assume it's filled in another column, like col8 or col 9.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm not sure about `mark 'sent' after sending them out.`, if "sent" is put to the column "J", from `I assume it's filled in another column, like col8 or col 9.` of your reply, I guessed that you wanted to put "sent" to the column "J" because the columns 8 and 9 (H and I) have already been used in your script. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet and save the script. And [please install OnEdit trigger to the function `sendMail`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually). By this, when the cell is edited, the script is run.

```js
function sendMail() {
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (ws.getSheetName() != "Email list") return;
  var name = 0;
  var request = 1;
  var id = 2;
  var select = 3;
  var time = 4;
  var email = 5;
  var status = 6;
  var error = 7;
  var emailTemp = {};
  var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email");
  var data = ws.getRange("A2:J" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var ranges = data.map(function (row, i) {
    if (row[8] == true && row[9] != "sent") {
      emailTemp.fn = row[name];
      emailTemp.req = row[request];
      emailTemp.id = row[id];
      emailTemp.erm = row[error];
      emailTemp.ta = row[select];
      emailTemp.time = row[time];
      var htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
      GmailApp.sendEmail(row[email],
        "Failure message",
        "Please submit again.",
        { name: "My name", htmlBody: htmlMessage }
      );
      return "J" + (i + 2);
    }
    return "";
  }).filter(String);
  ws.getRangeList(ranges).setValue("sent");
}
```

- In this case, when the active sheet is "Email list", the script is run. And, "sent" is put to the column "J".

#### Note:

- I think that the event object of OnEdit can be used. But from your question, I thought that you might want to directly run the script with the script editor. So I didn't use the event object.
- It seems that the columns 8 and 9 (H and I ) are used in your script like `emailTemp.erm = row[error];` and `data = data.filter(function(r){ return r[8] == true });`. So I put "sent" to the column "J". Please be careful this.

Comment: Thank you so much! I might make you confused about column & column 9, but I can take care of this mistake, thanks for the reminder! The script looks great and I'll spend some time reading the document of Onedit. One further question: what do you mean "event object"?

Comment: @Duh Thank you for replying. About the event object, you can see it at [this official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). For example, when the OnEdit trigger is run to the function of `function sendMail(e) {,,,}`, `e` has the information of the edited cell.

Comment: Your modified version of script works perfectly well, thank you so much!
Sorry but I got one further question: I tried to make onEdit(e) restricted to specific range in a single tab, therefore I create a simple trigger but got typeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined. I'll edit the question to put in the onEdit part. Can you please help?

Comment: @Duh Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your kind suggestion. And thank you again for helping out!

Comment: @Duh Thank you for your response. I found your new question. So I proposed an answer. If that was not useful, I apologize.